# Customize styling of not selected md-tab-label from md-tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I try to develop the following user interface for my angular material app. But I have no idea how I can customize all unselected md-tabs in CSS.

[This is what I want to have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD8Sl.png)

[Current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aONm1.png)

HTML Code:

```
        <md-tabs class="md-primary" md-selected="selectedIndex" md-align-tabs="top" md-autoselect md-dynamic-height id="top">
            <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" flex layout="column" layout-fill>
                <md-tab-label>
                    <div layout="row" layout-fill>
                        <div class="md-tab-item-index">
                            <span>{{tab.index}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="md-tab-item-label">
                            {{tab.title}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="md-tab-item-label-separator"></div>
                    </div>
                </md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
```

CSS

```
.md-tab-item-label {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.md-tab-item-label-separator {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 1px;
    min-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    width: 68px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.md-tab-item-index {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: can you run the code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is a version in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mueller92/c9w521ka/

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

`md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-ink-ripple md-active`
thats active one

`md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-ink-ripple`
thats not active one

Use your style to all, then prepare special style for active one.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't work.
Can you implement your solution in Fiddle?
jsfiddle.net/mueller92/c9w521ka